# Angular Binding to Promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I've got a bit of a promise problem in Angular. Meaning, I think I need to use promises to solve it, but I haven't cracked it yet.

Background

I have to display tooltips ('title' attribute) which are pulled from a Database Table. After retrieving them from the database, they come down the pipe as a collection of objects in json which look like this:

```
{ "helpMessageColumn": "GenderID", "message": "The gender of the person" }
```

Now, I needed a way to bind this to the title, so I used a function that I assigned to the scope:

```
<span title="{{findMessage('GenderID')}}" >
```

That function goes through the collection, finds the object with a helpMessageColumn of GenderID and returns the message property of that object.

The problem is, the promise which returns that data from the server has not resolved by the time the interpolation binding called findMessage. So the collection being searched is still undefined at that point.

So, I need to somehow (probably using promises), make sure that findMessage doesn't run until the data is there, or perhaps keeps trying until it is there or some such.

Alternative approaches are welcomed.

Cheers

Comment: When the promise resolves (assuming you're using `$http` or other Angular services), it should trigger a digest cycle and update the value in the DOM.

Comment: Demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/gST5IJBZg6XqOdYa6YG0?p=preview

Comment: @Phil Thanks Phil. All I had to do was guard against undefined. It does get populated on the new digest cycle. Happy to award answer if you put your comment as an answer. Cheers.